# Winforms call to async method hangs up program

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

I have been working around this problem for a while, but now I would really like to understand what goes wrong. I have a rather simple application (it's a turtoise SVN plugin for youtrack, but I can reproduce the problem with a trivial winforms app).

I have an async method `ResolveIssue`

```
public async Task<bool> ResolveIssue(Issue issue, int revision, string[] pathList)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    return true;
}
```

All I have to do to create a deadlock is call this async method in a `Button` event handler, and call `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result`, like this

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var asyncResolvedIssue = api.ResolveIssue(issue, revision, pathList);
    if (asyncResolvedIssue.Result) {} // <== deadlock!
}
```

Now I understand it's rather weird to have an async method and actively wait for it, but why would it generate a deadlock?!

Comment: Why the 2 down votes? At least share a comment.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your problem is because you are blocking the UI thread when you call `.Result` and you told the continuation after `Task.Delay` to run on the UI thread. So you are blocking the UI waiting for a task that is blocked on waiting for the UI to become free, a classic deadlock.

Two solutions. First make the button click async too.

```
private async void buttonOk_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var asyncResolvedIssue = api.ResolveIssue(issue, revision, pathList);
    if (await asyncResolvedIssue) {} // <== no deadlock!
}
```

Event handlers are the only place you are allowed to do `async void`.

The other option is tell `Task.Delay` it does not need to have the rest of its function run on the UI thread by setting [`ConfigureAwait(bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

```
public async Task<bool> ResolveIssue(Issue issue, int revision, string[] pathList)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return true;
}
```

Now the line of code after the `Task.Delay` will run on a threadpool thread instead of the UI thread and will not be blocked by the fact that the UI thread is currently blocked.

Comment: Shame on me for ASSUMING that I wouldn't be able to make my click event handler async.